# How to progressively make invisible a polygon?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I need to make progressively invisible a polygon with OpenGL ES 1.1. I'm developing for Android, but i think that other platforms will do the same code with some minor changes.

How i can do that?

Comment: WHat exactly do you mean by progressively? just change the alpha value of the color   ,in every frame do something like  colorA-=0.05f; glColor4f(1,0,0,colorA); ,Is this what you want?

Comment: my polygon haves a texture, is not a coloured polygon

Comment: Stop repeatedly asking the same question.

Comment: Use gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL10.GL_MODULATE);  after you bind the texture  this will compine the color of the texture with the color4f() color

Answer (score 0):

Create a FloatBuffer array, each FloatBuffer element contaning 4 floating point values.  The four values represent rgba values from 0.0f to 1.0f.  In the fourth element of each buffer, you can set the alpha value and for each element of the array you can incrementally change the alpha value.  Then create a method that references the elements of this array to apply the color properties.